# in ERB Inline code to fetch first non nil array value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I need to fetch first non nil value in an array.

I tried this code but doesnt seem to be work 
`entity['perattr.firstname'].to_s.find{|x|!x.nil?}`

it is giving me below error. Please let me know how to get the value?

> find' for "[]":String

Comment: Can you please add to your question an example value for `entity['perattr.firstname']`?

Answer (score 3):

To get the first non-nil value in an array, use [detect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect):

```
arr = [nil, nil, "foo", "bar", nil]
arr.detect{|x| !x.nil?}
=> "foo"
```

If `entity['perattr.firstname']` is an array, you can therefore just do

```
entity['perattr.firstname'].detect{|x| !x.nil?}
```

Don't call `to_s` on it, this will turn it into a string.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Still it's not working as its generating the error undefined method `html_safe' for nil:NilClass Hence, I added to_s to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

`to_s` is generally used to convert an object to String. Therefore irrespective of what value `entity['perattr.firstname']` holds, `entity['perattr.firstname'].to_s` will always be a String. Since there is no `find` method for String, you are getting error.

> find' for "[]":String